How can I get TSQL from easy MS Access SQL with little to no handiwork?
I have 500+ queries in a bunch of MS Access databases. The queries are rather easy.

(1.) I read them out with VBA into an Excel file as columns A to H, with the columns "ID, Datenbank, Objektname, LastUpdated, Objekttyp, Objektart, SourceTableName, Abfrage_SQL", with the last column being the query,
(2.) split the query with Regex into columns I to P as the split SQL blocks "Select, Into, From, Where, Group_By, Having, Order_By",
(3.) shortened the code with aliases into two new columns Q (New SQL Codes) and R (Mapping),
and my aim is to make (4.) a column S (TSQL) as the TSQL that I can take to feed an SSIS data flow.

For (3.), see In a standard MS Access SQL query output that does not have any aliases, how do I replace the full names by their "first-letters" aliases?, and there are also the links (1.)+(2.).
I need to change the MS Access VBA that is embedded in MS Access SQL, like Format() functions and special formats like #my_date#, and I do not want to Regex-replace the code dozens of times by hand in some Regex-Search-Replace menu. Instead, I want to loop over the replacements with Python, taking the output_file.xlsx from (3.) as the input and renaming the new output to output_file_tsql.xlsx. The output of the new TSQL code shall be put in a new column S (TSQL).
Which kind of Regex replacements might help as patterns for anyone to begin with? I am sure that the patterns in my 500+ queries are only a small share of what you can run into, but on the other hand, they should be a good sample for a cold start. You will have other patterns as well so that you cannot rely only on the examples. But then just answer and share what you found.
Is there a better way to get the TSQL from MS Access SQL than by Regex replacements? Any tool or trick can be an answer to this question.
How can I get TSQL from easy MS Access SQL with little to no handiwork?
(Old question was: "Which Regex replacements help when rewriting MS Access SQL queries as mere TSQL queries? How can these be looped over with Excel as input and output?")

Aside: You might want to look for a Microsoft Access SQL Parser. Once you have the query in the form of a parse tree that represents the semantics you can walk through it fixing up pieces or building a new query in a different dialect, e.g. T-SQL.

@HABO If you can show this for an easy example, it is worth an answer. I guess the parser does much the same and will be easier to deal with.

Parsers are, as a rule, nontrivial to deal with. The bright side is that you get the benefits of an analysis that follows all the syntax rules so that you never get tripped up by comments, quoted strings, badly chosen aliases, ... . Active Query Builder appears to be a commercial product that will get you to an object model of a query. There is a free .NET library for T-SQL parsing, but it doesn't handle Access.

@HABO I know this from XML parsers. I guess that for MS Access SQL to TSQL, the work with Regex is powerful enough. It can be done step by step for what you need, you can test it easily in regex101, and there are just 30 things I needed to parse 500+ easy queries.

This is fundamentally a bad idea. Access queries cannot be parsed to T-SQL code nontrivially, since they both support different features (e.g. dynamic pivots and multi-table updates aren't supported in single queries in T-SQL). But Access can parse its own queries to T-SQL just fine, and you can intercept these queries using ODBC tracing which would be much more reliable (and also make it obvious when a query cannot be parsed to T-SQL directly and requires multiple T-SQL queries to be executed).

@ErikA I have 500 + queries and I do not want to do this by hand.
I work on a ranking that sorts and blocks all of the dependencies so that nested queries, as they are done in MS Access by means of many queries that are built on top of each other, can be easily put into a TSQL nested query that might do this in one go instead. I do not know where I can do the ODBC tracing. If it is true that the queries can be read in a sort of TSQL log from that ODBC tracing, that would be the best way to go. It should be the answer here even if I have not asked it as such.

@ErikA I made the question more open to your remark.

@ErikA One advantage of doing it with the Regex replacements is that you do not need to run the queries at all when you prepare the setup. You can get the TSQL from 500+ queries in a second while running all of the queries can take time and nerves as well. Yet, I also need to run all of the queries afterwards when I put them in SSIS, that is why this is more a helpful framework to spin up SSIS.

@ErikA If you loop over all of the queries in VBA, you need to care about the dependencies that insert tables before you can run a child query of that. You might program all of this in MS Access VBA so that you can trace ODBC while running all of the queries, though. That is why your remark is still worth the accepted answer here.

The problem with your regexes is that they will fail for even very basic queries (e.g. SELECT Id FROM employees WHERE name = "O'Connel") and that they do not detect this. Getting them to actually work reliably using only regexes is near-impossible. They might work for your specific set of 500 queries, but using them on any other set is dangerous. They may work, they may fail, they may do second-order SQL injection. The VBA answer is very difficult, and does not really fit the SO format. I've done some of it during a migration, but handling all edge cases is hard even through VBA + tracing

@ErikA That is clear, I wanted to share a Regex collection here that anyone can take as a marker to begin with. You will surely find other challenges in another setting. My aim here was not to give a full list, but a list that shows a lot of patterns. For me, it is a great relief to get this done for 500+ queries even if there might still be some gaps in the Regex list. If I find something, I can do the seldom handiwork, but that is much better than doing such replacements again and again by hand, with all of the mistakes you can make. Or you put another Regex as for your example in the list.

The point I'm trying to get across is that you can't just put another regex in the list if you want to actually do this for complex queries. Escape single quotes inside double quoted strings taking into account that double quotes can be in variable names, single quoted strings, IN statements, etc would be a monstrous regex, while it's easy for a stateful parser to do. Regexes will only work if you can assure that all queries are simple ones.

@ErikA Then I am fine with some gaps if it is too hard to do. I have not yet checked the 500+ queries up to now since I want to know the dependencies inside the databases at first, I guess I will post that as well. As to the Regex, there will be some errors left in the code, but that does not harm if it happens seldomly.

@ErikA I made the query to sort the tables by their INTO-FROM dependencies, see the link at the bottom of the answer.

This code is mainly about Regex replacements in a loop, which will give you TSQL-only code from "MS Access SQL(VBA)" queries for the given 500+ queries set. As said above, you will surely run into other patterns as well, this is just to help how the frame and the patterns can look like.
import pandas as pd
import re

# Function to convert Access SQL to T-SQL
def convert_access_to_tsql(sql_string):
    if pd.isnull(sql_string) or sql_string.strip() == "":
        return ""  # Skip empty cells

    # Replace commas in the SELECT clause with a newline before each comma
    def replace_commas_in_select(match):
        select_clause = match.group(1)  # Captures the SELECT line
        other_part = match.group(2)  # Captures the rest (INTO, FROM, WHERE)

        # Replace commas in the select_clause with newline before each comma unless inside parantheses so that functions are skipped
        select_clause = re.sub(r',\s*(?![^(]*\))', r'\r\n,', select_clause)
        
        return f"{select_clause} {other_part}"
        
    select_pattern = r'^(SELECT.*?)(INTO|FROM|WHERE|$)'
    sql_string = re.sub(select_pattern, replace_commas_in_select, sql_string, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    # List of regex patterns and replacements
    replacements = [
        (r'Format\(\[?(\w+)?\]?!\[?(\w+)\]?,\s*""(.+?)""\)', r'convert(varchar(10), \1.\2, <Format function for \3>)'),
        (r'\[?(\w+)\]!?\[?(\w+)\]?', r'\1.\2'),
        (r'AS \[(\w+)\]', r'AS \1'),
        (r'\bJOIN\s+\[?(\w+)?\]?!\[?(\w+)\]\s+ON', r'JOIN \1.\2 ON'),
        (r'\bIs\b', r'IS'),
        (r'\bNull\b', r'NULL'),
        (r'\bOr\b', r'OR'),
        (r'convert\(varchar\(\d+\), \[?(\w+)\]?!\?(\w+)\?\)', r'convert(datetime, \1.\2)'),
        (r'Like "(\w+)\*"', r"LIKE '\1%'"),  # Convert asterisks at the end to T-SQL form
        (r'Like "\*(\w+)"', r"LIKE '%\1'"),  # Convert asterisks at the beginning to T-SQL form
        (r'Like "\*(\w+)\*"', r"LIKE '%\1%'"),  # Convert asterisks at both ends to T-SQL form
        (r'#(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})#', r"'\3-\1-\2'"),  # Correctly convert date format
        (r'Format\(\[?([\w|\.]+)\]?,\s*\"dd/mm/yyyy\"\)', r'convert(varchar(10), \1, 120)'),  # 115 would be dd/mm/yyyy Japanese, but my queries needed 120
        (r'Format\(\[?([\w|\.]+)\]?,\s*\"yyyy-mm-dd\"\)', r'convert(varchar(10), \1, 120)'),  # yyyy-mm-dd ODBC canonical
        (r'Format\(\[?([\w|\.]+)\]?,\"yyyy\"', r'convert(varchar(4), \1, 112)'),  # yyyy (from yyyymmdd)
        (r'Format\(\[?([\w|\.]+)\]?,\"dd\"', r'convert(varchar(2), \1, 104)'),  # dd
        (r'Date\(\)', r'CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)'),  # Replace VBA function
        (r'CInt\(', r'convert(int, '),  # Replace VBA function
        (r'"\s*([^"]*)\s*"', r"'\1'"),  # Replace "Text" with 'Text'
        (r'!(?!\[)', '.'),  # Replace ! with . except after [
        (r'\s*(INTO|AND|ON)', r'\r\n\1'),  # Replace INTO, AND, ON with line breaks
        (r'\s*AND', r'\r\n    AND'),  # Four spaces in front of AND
        (r'\s*ON', r'\r\n    ON'),  # Four spaces in front of ON      
        (r'\s*(JOIN\s+\w*|\w+\s+JOIN\s+\w*)', r'\r\n\1'),  # All types of JOIN with line breaks
        (r'(?<!\w)\(\s*([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*)\s*\)', r'\1'), # Remove parentheses (unless from a function) for simple dot notation (Step 1)
        (r'(?<!#)(\(\s*[^()]*![^()]*\))', r'1 = 1 --\1\n'),  # Comment out formular fields with exclamation marks, line break (Step 2)
        (r'\n\s*\n', r'\n'), # Drop empty line break (Step 3)
        (r'\bINTO\b', '--INTO'), # INTO blocks for nested queries in MS Access only
    ]

    # Loop through the replacements
    for pattern, replacement in replacements:
        try:
            sql_string = re.sub(pattern, replacement, sql_string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        except re.error as e:
            print(f"Regex error: {e} in pattern: {pattern} for string: {sql_string}")
            raise 

    # Post-processing conversion of date strings to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
    sql_string = re.sub(
        r"'(\d{1,4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})'",
        lambda m: f"'{int(m.group(1)):04}-{int(m.group(2)):02}-{int(m.group(3)):02}'",
        sql_string
    )

    return sql_string

# Load the Excel file and read the 'New SQL Codes' column
input_file = 'output_file.xlsx'
output_file = 'output_file_tsql.xlsx'

# Read the data
df = pd.read_excel(input_file)

# Ensure that the 'New SQL Codes' column exists
if 'New SQL Codes' not in df.columns:
    print("The column 'New SQL Codes' does not exist in the Excel file.")
else:
    # Process each cell in the 'New SQL Codes' column and write the result to column 'TSQL'
    df['TSQL'] = df['New SQL Codes'].apply(convert_access_to_tsql)

    # Save the modified DataFrame as a new Excel file
    df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)

print(f"The file has been successfully saved as {output_file}.")

The output is the column S filled with 500+ TSQL queries without any MS Access functions and formats and with line breaks before each column and before some SQL keywords, AND and ON four spaces indented.
With its output at hand, you can also sort it by the levels of dependencies with the help of How do I sort "SELECT INTO" queries that are built on top of each other by their "INTO" / "FROM" table links?.
